# ListView is not showing nested inside Row and Column

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to know why I can not see the ListView content if I put it in Row that is inside Column?
Thank you

```
body: Center(
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Flexible(
            child: ListView(
              children: [
                Text('Text 1'),
                Text('Text 2'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

I did put the ListView inside Flexible but it is not working.

Comment: did you tried to change the AxisDirection to horizontal in the ListView

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap the `ListView` with `Expanded` widget, it will take available space.

```
 Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(
        //this
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              //this
              child: ListView(
                children: [
                  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) Text('Text $i'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Check more about [Unbounded height / width | Decoding Flutter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jckqXR5CrPI)

Comment: Thank you for your solution and explanation. 
The problem with this solution is that the ListView is not scrollable. How do I enable it?

Comment: are you placing `Center`  inside scaffold body & it will be scroll-able when items gets beyond view viewport ?

Comment: Yes, the code looks like this:
`body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: ListView(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      children: [
                        Text('Text 1'),`

Comment: You need to provide more children height

Comment: How can I do this? Can you give me some example?
Thank you

Comment: ok, added loop to generate more item

Comment: Glad to help, you can find more about [layout](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout)

Answer (score 1):

If you run your code, you will see this error:

```
Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.
```

Which means that the height isn't constrained.

You should set [`shrinkWrap`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollView/shrinkWrap.html):

> Whether the extent of the scroll view in the scrollDirection should be
> determined by the contents being viewed.
>
> If the scroll view does not shrink wrap, then the scroll view will
> expand to the maximum allowed size in the scrollDirection. If the
> scroll view has unbounded constraints in the scrollDirection, then
> shrinkWrap must be true.

to `true`:

```
ListView(
  shrinkWrap: true,
   children: [
   Text('Text 1'),
   Text('Text 2'),
    ],
)
```

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Flexible(
                    child: ListView(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      children: [
                        Text('Text 1'),
                        Text('Text 2'),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @MendelG for your solution and explanation. Now the problem is that the ListView is not scrollable. Does anyone know how to make it?